# How to use a PHP file which displays json array directly

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a interaction between HTML and PHP using jQuery and AJAX.

I put a url with GET parameters, and the PHP file prints an JSON array with the data returned by my database. Then I show it in my HTML.

```
<?php
   if (isset($_GET["vari"]) && isset($_GET["vari2"])){
      echo json_encode(array("hello", $_GET["vari"], $_GET["vari2"]);
   }
?>
```

What I want to do is when someone open the url of the PHP file with GET parameters then will be redirected to my HTML file and show here information as I do with jQuery and AJAX. But, obviusly, when I open the PHP I see the JSON array... 
So I found this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // JSON
} else {
    // HTML
}
```

but if I want to load index.html file externaly and show the data of the parameters, what I should do? becouse if I use header('index.html') or echo file_get_contents('index.html') then I can't send the parameters. I explain?

I'm looking for the best way to do it, do you have some advice?
I hope I was clear, but if you need more information to help me let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: show your code!! show sqample output

Comment: Please stop italicizing every other word. It's very distraction to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check if the request is done through AJAX and if so, only display the JSON response.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // JSON
} else {
    // HTML
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! but then I'll need to have all in the same file, true? there is another way?

Comment: That depends how you write your code. You can put the logic in your controller and either output JSON based on the request method or call the file / function that contains your HTML.

Comment: I've updated the post. I hope now you uderstand what I'm trying to explain. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

#### The quick and dirty solution that works

The "detect if AJAX" approach would be an immediate practical solution to the problem. However, it is much better to let the client *specify* what kind of content it wants to receive.

#### The more flexible but also more involved and still somewhat dirty solution

A number of application frameworks do this by detecting the presence of a `.type` suffix in the url. For example, `http://path/to/data.json` would return JSON and `http://path/to/data.html` or plain `http://path/to/data` would return HTML. However, to set this up you need to either have a specific URL structure and use a front controller script or access to the web server configuration.

To implement this with just PHP, the idea is that your URLs would look like `/.../data.php/json` and `data.php` would do something like:

```
$data = array('Sample' => 'data');

switch (strtolower($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
    case '/json':
        echo json_encode($data);
        break;
    default:
        print_r($data);
        break;
}
```

#### The purest but also not too convenient and definitely hard to implement solution

Technically the correct approach would be to let the client specify the type through the HTTP `Accept` header, which was created exactly for this purpose. This has the advantage that it is "by the book", but it makes it more difficult to access this functionality (whereas passing in a `.json` suffix to the url is trivial).

Here's a barebones example of how to do this using the `Accept` header:

```
$data = array('Sample' => 'data');

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], "application/json") === false) {
    print_r($data);
}
else {
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Please be aware that the above code is critically under-featured since it does not attempt to properly parse the header properly, which it definitely should. However, properly determining the client's preferred content type is not trivial.

Comment: Thanks! Good explanation! I've updated the post, you can give me some help now?

Comment: @Joëlle: I don't understand what you are trying to describe.

Comment: Ok, I have `hello.php?var1=foo&var2=bye` which displays json array with the GET variables. If I call the url with jQuery and AJAX from index.html I can show the data in a <div> (in this case: foo and bye). So my question is: If the user put `hello.php?var1=123&var2=dfg` and its not called by the jQuery of the index.html file, then I'd display the index.html with the <div> with the parameters (in the second case: 123 and dfg).

Answer (score 0):

On start of your  .php page you can right this way.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != 'XMLHttpRequest')
{
    header('Location: index.html'); // Your HTML page url
}
```

Hope this will work for you. :)

Enajoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to do that:
I created a constant in application enviroment(I put it in my frontcontroller) for this case, like:

```
define('AJAX_CALL', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

With it, now you can ask for the type of the call

```
if(AJAX_CALL){
//do stuff
}
```

Also, you can define a variable that indicates if is ajax or not, add it to the data sent. If you pass a json object with the another data, add, {ajax:true} and then in the php file:

```
if($_GET['ajax']){
  //do stuff
}
```

I hope it is useful.